# Ramifications of exporting original .ts files instead of .d.ts files as module type declarations

Tags: typescript

A typical TypeScript module contains `src` directory with TypeScript source code files, runs `tsc -d --outDir dist` to compile the sources to `dist`, and sets the following package metadata to let both Node.js runtime and TypeScript compiler understand what the module is exporting:

```
{
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": ["dist"]
}
```

To make debugging easier, it's often desired for packages to ship source-maps and the original source code too.

With the recently introduced [Project References](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html) and the compiler option `--declarationMap`, I feel modules should provide declaration map files too, to allow IDEs to jump from places calling module APIs directly to the implementation, not to the generated `.d.ts` files.

As a result, a module is going to pack the following files:

- transpiled `.js` files needed by runtime
- original `.ts` files needed for debugging
- declarations in `.d.ts` needed by TypeScript compiler
- declaration maps in `.d.ts.map` needed by IDE tooling

This setups seems overly complicated to me and begs a question - what if we got rid of `.d.ts` and `.d.ts.map` files and shipped the original TypeScript sources instead?

```
{
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "src/index.ts",
  "files": ["src", "dist"]
}
```

Few downsides that come to my mind:

- When compiling a project depending on my module, TypeScript compiler will have more work to do. Instead of parsing dense `.d.ts` files, it has to parse full `.ts` sources. The build may be slower as a result.
- Similarly for IDEs like VSCode: instead of loading `.d.ts.map` files that are most likely optimized for fast parsing, the language service has to parse full `.ts` sources.

There is also a subtle difference between `.d.ts` and `.ts` files. The former export declarations only (e.g. `declare class Foo {}`), while the latter exports definitions (e.g. `class Foo {}`). I am not entirely familiar with the way how TypeScript handles the case where there are multiple instances of the same module present in the dependency tree. Will it treat multiple copies of a declaration differently from multiple copies of a definition?

Are there any other arguments against using original `.ts` files as type declarations?

Answer (score 2):

> it's often desired for packages to ship source-maps and the original
>   source code too.

This is partly true. A source map *does* contain your source code already. That's why DevTools are capable of re-creating the original source from minified JavaScript code if only the source map is present.

One disadvantage I can see is the size of your package. Declaration files are lightweight. Most of the libraries could probably be described with a single declaration file smaller than 100 lines of code.

However, small API surface doesn't mean there was not much source code. You could have a project that consists of thousands of modules, yet its public API is a single interface. Using a `*.d.ts` file to describe it allows your consumers to save a significant amount of space on their machines.